# in zsh, how do I get pwd in my prompt?

Tags: zsh, prompt

I've recently switched from bash to zsh,
but it annoys me that I can't see what directory I'm in (MacOSX)

how do I get 'pwd' to show up in my prompt?

Answer (score 10):

```
PROMPT="%~$ "
```

Comment: Run 'echo $PROMPT' to see current PROMPT configuration.

Answer (score 4):

```
PROMPT='%d%>:%{\e[0m%}>> '
```

Comment: This is unusable...

Comment: @TomSlick I just tested it again and it works fine for me. What trouble are/were you having?

Answer (score 2):

Here is mine on MAC

```
PROMPT='$fg[cyan]%m:$fg[yellow] %T %B%30<..<%~%b %(!.#.>) '
```

[. . . looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k3ym.png)

Comment: This worked but partially.  No colours.  Fixed it by replacing `fg[cyan]` with `%F{cyan}`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but I use this for my zsh. Add this line to `~/.zshrc` ...

```
export PROMPT='%m:%~ %n %# '
```

And it looks like this:

```
ik1nes-MacBook-Pro:~ ik1ne %
```

If you're curious what each symbol means, you can type `man zshmisc` and look for SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES section.

Answer (score 1):

I know It's been a while, but I just put this answer here as it is another approach. You can do it like this too:

```
#this is your PROMPT
PROMPT='$fg[cyan]%m: $fg[yellow]$(get_pwd) '
#this is the function
function get_pwd() {
    echo "${PWD/$HOME/~}"
}
```

P.S: I recommend you to use [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/)